# can i change styles in react js packages?

Tags: reactjs

i want to have some changes in `material ui` package to make my custom text field i achieved what i was looking for in chrome devtools 
i was wondering if i can change the package's style
here is what i want to achieve

[image]

this was in chrome devtools

this is what i currently have

[image]

Comment: would not recommend you change the package without sending in a PR, having that PR approved and integrated. What's the issue with using a custom CSS file?

Comment: i'm not familiar with custom css file, in that ,can i add my own transition for that or i should create my custom ui for the text field ?

Comment: Yes. Create a CSS file and add your custom CSS transitions/transforms that you put into the console into that file. Then include that with your React app.

Comment: i used @SomoKRoceS 's answer , that solved my problem ,thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the common used UI packages gives you, as long with the components API, a styling API.

Material UI has a styling [API](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/) using `makeStyles`.
Please refer to the basics of styling [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/).